# How to uncheck radio buttons(which are in radiogroup) in android?

Tags: android, radio-button

```
        RadioGroup group=(RadioGroup)findviewbyid(R.id.group);
        RadioButton b=(RadioButton)findviewbyid(R.id.button);
        RadioButton b1=(RadioButton)findviewbyid(R.id.button1);
        RadioButton b2=(RadioButton)findviewbyid(R.id.button2);

        group.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        selected=(RadioButton)findViewById(checkedId);
        userAnswer=selected.getText().toString();
          }
        });

      button=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.butn);
      button.setOnclickListener(new View.OnclickListener(){
      void onclick()
      {
      group.clearCheck();
       }
      });
```

my requirement is whenever user clicks on next button i need to show the radio buttons as options without the selection.if user clicks an option and he clicks next button then whatever the option he clicked(checked) previously that is selecting automatically for the next time, before that i need to clear the radiobuttons in the radiogroup for that what i have to do......

Thanks in advance.......

Comment: What Happened when you use the above code? What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Try defining `RadioGroup group` as a class member not as local for onCreate();

Comment: Please show your xml code.

Answer (score 9):

Also have you added the RadioButtons within the RadioGroup View in your xml? If not you need to add them to the RadioGroup object you are using

You need to use methods from the RadioGroup

```
   void     check(int id)   
  Sets the selection to the radio button whose identifier is passed in parameter.


  void  clearCheck()
   /// This method will clear the selection of all the members of RadioGroup
```

For example if rg is a variable of RadioGroup

```
         rg.check();
         rg.clearCheck();
```